# kendo button click validation messages are not showing mvc4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

Here am using kendo button .and razor textboxes .Am not getting validation messages on button click
here is my code

```
<tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.Label("User Name")
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { Class = "txtLogin" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.Label("Password")
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { Class = "txtLogin" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <div class="fielddiv">
                                            @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                                            .Name("btnsave")
                                            .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" })
                                            .Content("Login"))
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if everything is nested in a `form` tag (or `Html.BeginForm`). Then set the type of the button to "submit".